# One Activity Two or more NavHostFragment

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

Is it possible to create an app that has one activity, but two NavHostFragment. One of the NavHostFragment will be in the activity, while the other one will be within one of the fragments. The fragment would point to a nested graph

Comment: Why not to use nested graph with one NavHostFragment?

Comment: @Alex If you could point me an example that shows who that would work

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing#group

Comment: Let assume I am using BottonNavigationView in one Fragment, and I want to keep showing it as long as I am on same level. but then I go into another fragment which on different level which has bottomAppBar and Navigation drawer and I want keep showing those as long as I am on the same level. Can do this with on NavHostFragment on the Activity or should I have different NavHost on the Fragments Level

Comment: How did you handle this situation?

Comment: @mrJoe i did not find a solution. :(

Comment: Well, in my case I finally created one navhost in activity and the other one in one of fragments and it works as expected. They both use independent graphs to navigate between destinations.